# pstricks pscustom deforms object

Tags: pstricks, pscustom

if I combine `\psline` and `\pscurve` to create an object and put it into `\pscustom`, the object gets deformed. To me it looks like the bezier curve gets some additional boundary conditions due to closing the paths, but I might be completly mistaken there.

This example is part of a bigger scetch (therefore the maybe strange numbers), I tried to scetch a concave lense:

```
 \begin{pspicture}(.2,1)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray, linestyle=dashed]{
        \psline(2.9,2.15)(3.1,2.15)
        \pscurve(3.1,2.15)(3.03,1.65)(3.1,1.15)
        \psline(3.1,1.15)(2.9,1.15)
        \pscurve(2.9,1.15)(2.97,1.65)(2.9,2.15)}

    \psline(2.9,2.15)(3.1,2.15)
    \pscurve(3.1,2.15)(3.03,1.65)(3.1,1.15)
    \psline(3.1,1.15)(2.9,1.15)
    \pscurve(2.9,1.15)(2.97,1.65)(2.9,2.15)
 \end{pspicture}
```

Doubling and `linestyle=dashed` ofc just for demonstration. 
Is there anyway to fill the object like I get outside `\pscustom`?

[image: example output]

Answer (score 5):

`\pscustom` creates a closed path. It uses the last point of a line/curve also for the next line/curve. This is the reason why you need only 2 points
for a curve which follows a line or another curve and only one point for a line. The first point is always the last point from the preceding macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=10}
 \begin{pspicture}(2.5,1)(4,3)
 \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray, linestyle=dashed]{
    \psline(2.9,2.15)(3.1,2.15)
    \pscurve(3.03,1.65)(3.1,1.15)
    \psline(2.9,1.15)
    \pscurve(2.97,1.65)(2.9,2.15)}

 \psline(2.9,2.15)(3.1,2.15)
 \pscurve(3.1,2.15)(3.03,1.65)(3.1,1.15)
 \psline(3.1,1.15)(2.9,1.15)
 \pscurve(2.9,1.15)(2.97,1.65)(2.9,2.15)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\psline(0,0)(1,1)\pscurve(1,1)(3,1)(4,2)` insinde `\pscustom` is drawn
as `\pscurve(1,1)(1,1)(3,1)(4,2)` which is different to 
`\pscurve(1,1)(3,1)(4,2)`